# How to divide the column by the row count and then rank it on a scale of 1 to 5, 5 being the largest in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a project to automate a report wherein I have to write a query in mysql to get it done automatically. Have been trying to look for this endlessly on the net but to no avail :(
here is a dummy data

[Emp table sorted by salary descending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbC4W.png)

`{Empname  | Salary}`
   `Ellen     |  45030`
   `Claudia   |  40000`
   `collin    |  25000`
   `Meghan    |  24350`
   `Angelika  |  24000`
   `John      |  20000`
   `Smith     |  20000`
   `Adam      |  16555`
   `Andrew    |  16000`
   `Mayer     |  13000`

I need to first divide the salary row count by 5 and then have it grouped by the output, so if the row count is 10 for example it would be 10/5= 2, so the column needs to be grouped in to 2 and then rank the top 2 as 5, next two as 4 and so on, please note the row count would change everytime
Desired output as below

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwmpn.png)

`{Empname  | Salary    | Salary Rank}`
   `Ellen     |  45030    | 5`
   `Claudia   |  40000    | 5`
   `collin    |  25000    | 4`
   `Meghan    |  24350    | 4`
   `Angelika  |  24000    | 3`
   `John      |  20000    | 3`
   `Smith     |  20000    | 2`
   `Adam      |  16555    | 2`
   `Andrew    |  16000    | 1`
   `Mayer     |  13000    | 1`

I have been trying the below code which I found however it doesn't assign the rank based on the value in the salary column, also the ranking isn't from 5 to 1

```
select ceil(rnk/5.0) as grp,
`salary`, `emp name`
FROM
(
  select e.`salary`, e.`emp name`,
  (SELECT count(*) from `empdata` d
    where e.`salary`< d.`salary`) + 1 as rnk
   from `empdata` e
  )x
order by `salary` desc
```

Comment: don't post image  ..(only), update your question  and  post sample as  text tabular data too .and post the also the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge please could you help me on how to add the text tabular data instead of an image unable to do so, i just comes up as a plain text

Comment: yous should add  a text with the values  ..   .. eg:copy the data you have in your SQL IDE or worksheet ..

Comment: unfortunately whatever I copy here is getting pasted as a plain text vertically

Comment: you can use curly bracket for format the palin text  .

Comment: finally i have it formatted